# Setting data members with generic setter

Tags: c++, reflection, introspection

I'm trying to implement a superclass in c++ that would implement one method:

```
-void setValueForKey(void *value, string key);
```

all this method would have to do is to set the value of a property associated with a given key to the new value.
This would be easy in a language that implements introspection mechanisms; as far as I know C++ doesn't.

In order to accomplish this I created another method:

```
void registerKeyForProperty(void *propertyPtr, string key);
```

all this method does is it stores in and internal map a pointer to a property associated with a given key, so all my subclasses would call this for every property they declare and I would have a way of setting values for properties without necessity to use the setters.(That's what I need!) (I explain why at the end of the post...)

for this second function I have the following implementation:

```
void registerKeyForProperty(void *propertyPtr, string key){

   _keysDictionary->insert(pair<string,void*>(key,property));
}
```

where _keysDictionary is a stl map.

for the first one I have the following implementation:

```
void ConstructableObject::setValueForKey(void* value, string key) {

    map<string,void *>::iterator it=_keysDictionary->find(key);

    if(it==_keysDictionary->end()){return;}//just return if there is nothing for that key

    void *property=it->second;

    (*property)=value;
}
```

the problem is the last line is not legal C++ because ofcourse I cannot just deference that void*.

My questions are:

Is there any other way of implementing the desired functionality?
Is there a "legal" way of doing this the way I am doing it? (I cannot simply use a reinterpret_cast cause I don't know what to cast to...)

Why this:

I need to parse and xml file that has some information about some objects. I'll be using TinyXML and therefore I'll have the atribute names for the objects and their values. That would be how I would like to use it:

```
MyClass obj();//the constructor would call setValueForKey(...,...) for every property so all are now registered
for every attribute{
    obj.setValueForKey(attribute.value,attribute.name);
}

//all properties should be set now
```

Answer (score 1):

If the key exists, why not simply do

```
_keysDictionary[key] = value;
```

Or if you want to use the iterator

```
it->second = value;
```

Comment: I might be wrong but _keysDictionary[key] is a pointer to a data member not the data member itself, so changing the value of the pointer wouldn't change the value of the data member, just set the pointer to point somewhere else, not the data member any longer. Am I not write?

Comment: @Mppl So in the map you store a pointer to the pointer? I.e. something like `void**`? Have you by the way thought about [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with using of the type awareness techniques and for example The Memento Pattern is one of choices. The following code could be extended with the some macro stuff that generating the unique keys based on the attribute pointer signature:

```
class introspection
{
public:
  template <typename Class, typename Member>
  void registerKey(std::string key, Member Class::*memberPointee, Class* classPointee)
  {
    typedef member_setter<Class, Member> hold_member_pointer;
    base_setter* setter = new hold_member_pointer(memberPointee, classPointee);
    keys.insert(std::make_pair(key, setter));
  }

  template <typename Value>
  void setValue(std::string key, Value value)
  {
    if ( keys.count(key) > 0 )
    {
      keys[key]->set(value);
    }
    else
    {
      throw std::logic_error("no such key");
    }
  }

private:
  struct base_setter
  {
    virtual void set(boost::any value) = 0;
  };  // struct base_setter

  template <typename Class, typename Member>
  struct member_setter : base_setter
  {
    member_setter(Member Class::*memberPointee, Class* classPointee)
    : memberPointee(memberPointee)
    , classPointee(classPointee) {}

    void set(boost::any value) override
    {
      Member newValue = boost::any_cast<Member>(value);
      classPointee->*memberPointee = newValue;
    }

    Member Class::*memberPointee;
    Class*          classPointee;
  };  // struct member_setter

  std::map<std::string, base_setter*> keys;
};  // class introspection

struct Data
{
  int value;
};  // struct Data

int main()
{
  introspection i;
  Data d;
  d.value = 100;
  i.registerKey("value", &Data::value, &d);
  i.setValue("value", 200);           // OK
  i.setValue("value", "not valid");   // bad_any_cast
}
```

The one thing that could be (not so easily) improved here is provide the compile-time type check for setValue, instead of runtime any_cast casting.

Answer (score 0):

Make setValueForKey be a templated function instead of a function that accepts a void pointer.  That way, you can know about the type information of the property long enough to create a templated setter

```
class BaseSetter
{
    public:
        virtual void set(void* inValue) = 0;
}

template <typename T>
class SpecializedSetter
{
    public:
        SpecializedSetter(T* inMyValue)
        : mValue(inValue)
        { }

        virtual void set(void* inValue)
        {
            *mValue = *reinterpret_cast<T*>(inValue);
        }
   private:
        T* mValue;
}


template <typename T>
void registerKeyForProperty(T* inValue, string inKey)
{
    registerSetterForProperty(new SpecificSetter<T>(inValue), inKey);
}
```

This, however, assumes inValue is a pointer to the same type of data as the value on the class.  To make that safe, consider `boost::any` or defining some other type which contains the type information from the XML file and using that rather than void*